# Why do some pages on the website turn completely white after refreshing a few times?

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js13

I'm building a website using Next.js 13 (with the app router).

When I attempt to refresh certain pages multiple times, the page becomes completely white, and I receive the following message in the console: "This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode, use `<!DOCTYPE html>`."

The page remains white until I terminate the app and then run it again.

I don't have any problem with the other pages in the website, it just a certain pages.

I do not encounter this problem during development time (using `npm run dev`); it only appears during production time (when I use `npm start`).

this is the app's layout page:

```
   import './globals.css'
    import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
    import { Navigation } from '@/components/nav';
    import Provider from '@/redux/provider';
    import { Setup } from '@/components/utils';


    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

    export const metadata = {
      title: 'English Learning through pictures',
      description: 'guess images with cards and space repetetion system',
    }

    export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
      return (
        <html lang="en"> 
          <body className={inter.className}>       
            <Provider>  
            <Setup/>
            <Navigation/>
            {children}
            </Provider>
            </body>
        </html>
      )
    }
```

I tried searching online for the problem but couldn't find anything.

Perhaps I need to customize the layout page, but I'm hesitant to modify the original Next.js layout page until I fully understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the beginning of your HTML structure in the RootLayout component:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en"> 
        <body className={inter.className}>       
          <Provider>  
            <Setup/>
            <Navigation/>
            {children}
          </Provider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I can't add <!DOCTYPE html> like this, it's an error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the NexJ JS 13 revalidation fetching data. I changed the interval from 5 seconds to 1000 seconds.

I also attempted intervals of 300 and 500 seconds, but the problem persists. It only resolved when I set it to more than 1000 seconds.